# Using Count in Terraform to create Launch Configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have 3 different version of an AMI, for 3 different nodes in a cluster.

```
data "aws_ami" "node1"
{
  # Use the most recent AMI that matches the pattern below in 'values'.
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name = "name"
    values = ["AMI_node1*"]
  }

  filter {
    name = "tag:version"
    values = ["${var.node1_version}"]
  }

}

data "aws_ami" "node2"
{
  # Use the most recent AMI that matches the pattern below in 'values'.
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name = "name"
    values = ["AMI_node2*"]
  }

  filter {
    name = "tag:version"
    values = ["${var.node2_version}"]
  }

}

data "aws_ami" "node3"
{
  ...
}
```

I would like to create 3 different Launch Configuration and Auto Scaling Group using each of the AMIs respectively.

```
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "node"
{
  count = "${local.node_instance_count}"
  # Name-prefix must be used otherwise terraform fails to perform updates to existing launch configurations due to
  # a name conflict: LCs are immutable and the LC cannot be destroyed without destroying attached ASGs as well, which
  # terraform will not do. Using name-prefix lets a new LC be created and swapped into the ASG.
  name_prefix = "${var.environment_name}-node${count.index + 1}-"
  image_id = "${data.aws_ami.node[count.index].image_id}"
  instance_type = "${var.default_ec2_instance_type}"
 ...
}
```

However, I am not able use `aws_ami.node1`, `aws_ami.node2`, `aws_ami.node3` using the cound.index the way I have shown above. I get the following error:

```
Error reading config for aws_launch_configuration[node]: parse error at 1:39: expected "}" but found "."
```

Is there another way I can do this in Terraform?

Comment: from the comments below I see you're trying to create a kafka cluster, i found this post due to attempting the same thing. I'm trying to utilize count with launch configs & auto scale groups to use a different user-data section for each of three nodes to set the myid file to a unique id. not having a lot of luck, i'm going to go the most simplistic route for now and just have 3 each launch cofigs & auto scale groups. I feel there is a better way to do this though.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing data sources isn't something that's doable; at the moment.

You're likely better off simply dropping the `data` sources you've defined and codifying the image IDs into a Terraform `map` variable.

```
variable "node_image_ids" {
  type        = "map"

  default = {
    "node1" = "1234434"
    "node2" = "1233334"
    "node3" = "1222434"
  }
}
```

Then, consume it:

```
image_id = "${lookup(var.node_image_ids, concat("node", count.index), "some_default_image_id")}"
```

The downside of this is that you'll need to manually update the image id when images are upgraded.

Comment: Can I create a list using the `data.aws_ami` like this?
`ami_image_id_list = ["${data.aws_ami.kafka-node1.image_id}", "${data.aws_ami.kafka-node2.image_id}", "${data.aws_ami.kafka-node3.image_id}"] `

Comment: you could likely create a `local` variable (either a `list` or `string`) and store the data source values. then use some `interpolation` method to extract the values dynamically.

Comment: Thanks. This is not possible:
`variable "ami_image_id_list" {
  type        = "map"
  default = {
    "kafka-ami-node1" = "${data.aws_ami.kafka-node1.image_id}"
    "kafka-ami-node2" = "${data.aws_ami.kafka-node2.image_id}"
    "kafka-ami-node3" = "${data.aws_ami.kafka-node3.image_id}"
  }
}` because  variable cannot contain interpolations.

Comment: How do I `interpolate` dynamically?